# Received an unrequested business credit card - identity theft?

Tags: credit-card, business

I received a "Divvy business card" in the mail.  I didn't apply for this card.  The mail contains my name "cardholder name" and doesn't seem to be just spam.  I do have an LLC but it does little and I haven't used it to apply for anything.  The LLC is associated with a Bluevine small-business checking account and in the past a Wise account.

Why did Divvy send me this?

Comment: Does the letter with the card discuss the credit limit and other terms?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep It's a simple letter lacking details but pointing the way to those: "Wecome to Divvy, download the app, activate your card, spend but smarter". The card it comes with has a chip and an activation sticker.

Comment: "Activate your card" probably actually involves all the usual steps for opening a credit line.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds more like cold-calling marketing -- or phishing -- than anything else, to me. I'd send back an "I never requested account, please cancel" note just in case, then file it in case I need to refer back to it, and consider it handled. If they demand more info than was on what they sent you in order to cancel, they can Go Phish.

Comment: My son in college got a similar cold-mailed card. Really slimy of them (he never activated and called them to chastise them).

Comment: @JonCuster The phone center people don't have enough sway to really do anything even if you blast them. Report the company to BBB.